# Making Textbox in VB Inputbox Larger

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

How can I make the textbox in a VB Inputbox larger?

Comment: WPF, Silverlight, WinForms, WP7?

Comment: @NickHeidke I am just making a VB.NET Executable.

Comment: @Odinuff: What kind of executable? Are you using System.Windows.Forms? System.Web.UI.WebControls?

Comment: @IAbstract The default in a Windows Forms application, which I would assume would thus be System.Windows.Forms....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the input box, just create your own custom input box.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. How would I do that?

Comment: google for "creating custom controll vb.net" there are plenty posts about it.

Comment: Basically you just create your own form that looks/acts like the inputbox control. With that you will be able to modify the height and width, really anything you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiline textbox if thats what you mean. Or you can create a new inputbox form and add a multiline textbox to it and set the anchor to all directions, so if you change the form size it will change its size as well.

Or you could use a normal textbox and just change the font size.